# How can i assign each browser task to have its own randomly generated ID so i can access it at any time?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm wondering how i can assign ID's to each browser window that i open so i can track it and maybe access it later. I'm currently using a For loop to make each browser but in this i want to give each browser its own individual id. I would like to use this id for say maybe if i want to close browser id # 5 i have a button that closes just that browser and i wont have to do it manually and find the browser i need closed. Or maybe if i want to refresh browser # 3 i can just click a button and it automatically access that. I'm doing this in python so any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been a huge roadblock for me.

```
        def start():
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
            ua = UserAgent()
            user_agent = ua.random
            options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
            options.add_argument("window-size=600,600")
            options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
            options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
            options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
            options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
            options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list")
            options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
            driver.set_window_size(500, 500)
            driver.set_window_position(70, 70)
            driver.get(page_address)
            browsers_opn.append(driver.get(page_address))
```

I also am looping to create labels and buttons for each browser window in another tab in my UI. This is the code that is doing that.

```
he = 50
            s = 95
            m = 235
            n = 435
            ss = 670
            hee = 45

            for task in range(0, num_tasks):
                Label(page2, text=page_name, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=s, y=he)
                Label(page2, text=proxy_address, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=m, y=he)
                Label(page2, text=stat, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=n, y=he)
                button1 = Button(page2, text='Start', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10),
                                 command=start).place(x=ss, y=hee)
                # button2 = Button(page2, text='Stop', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10), command=stop).place(x=ss + 25, y=hee)
                tasks_btns.append(button1)
                # tasks_btns.append(button2)
                he = he + 30
                hee = hee + 30
```

With each button i make it has the command that when clicked to open a browser. What i want to now be able to do is to track the browser and have it specifically assigned to its own id which i then can create buttons that will close or minimize or even refresh that specific browser window. Something like browserid1.close(). im not sure how i can do this in a for loop though.

here is my entire code for reference:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('FlashCop')
root.geometry('1000x750')
root.configure(bg='#2C3E50')
style = ttk.Style()
chrome_path = "chromedriver.exe"

style.theme_create("cool", parent="classic", settings={
    "TNotebook": {"configure": {"background": '#2C3E50', "tabmargins": [2, 5, 20, 0]}},
    "TNotebook.Tab": {
        "configure": {"padding": [5, 1], "background": '#2C3E50', "foreground": '#FDFEFE', 'font': ("Helvetica", '12')},
        "map": {"background": [("selected", '#212F3D')],
                "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])], }}})

page_name = ''
page_address = ''


def add_tasks():
    global page_name
    global page_address
    is_head = y_nh.get().lower()
    y_proxy = y_n.get().lower()
    tasks_btns = []
    browsers_opn = []

    if y_proxy == 'no' or y_proxy == 'n':
        proxy_address = 'N/A'

        def start():
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
            ua = UserAgent()
            user_agent = ua.random
            options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
            options.add_argument("window-size=600,600")
            options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
            options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
            options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
            options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
            options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list")
            options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
            driver.set_window_size(500, 500)
            driver.set_window_position(70, 70)
            driver.get(page_address)
            browsers_opn.append(driver.get(page_address))

        if is_head == 'yes' or is_head == 'y':
            print("do headless mode")
        else:
            options = Options()
            stat = 'IDLE'
            site_page = site.get()
            if site_page == 'ys' or site_page == 'yeezysupply':
                page_name = 'YeezySupply'
                page_address = 'https://yeezysupply.com/'
            elif site_page == 'adidas':
                page_name = 'Adidas'
                page_address = 'https://www.adidas.com/yeezy'
            num_tasks = int(num.get())
            he = 50
            s = 95
            m = 235
            n = 435
            ss = 670
            hee = 45

            for task in range(0, num_tasks):
                Label(page2, text=page_name, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=s, y=he)
                Label(page2, text=proxy_address, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=m, y=he)
                Label(page2, text=stat, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=n, y=he)
                button1 = Button(page2, text='Start', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10),
                                 command=start).place(x=ss, y=hee)
                # button2 = Button(page2, text='Stop', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 10), command=stop).place(x=ss + 25, y=hee)
                tasks_btns.append(button1)
                # tasks_btns.append(button2)
                he = he + 30
                hee = hee + 30

                def startall():
                    driver = None
                    ua = None
                    for start_tasks in range(0, num_tasks):
                        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
                        ua = UserAgent()
                        user_agent = ua.random
                        driver.set_window_size(350, 350)
                        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
                        options.add_argument("--window-size=600,600")
                        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
                        options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
                        options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
                        options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
                        options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list")
                        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
                        driver.set_window_position(70, 70)
                        driver.get(page_address)

                start_all = Button(page2, text='Start All', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14),
                                   command=startall)
                start_all.place(x=900, y=5)


firstclick = True


def on_entry_click(event):
    global firstclick
    if firstclick:
        firstclick = False
        site.delete(0, 'end')


def saveproxy():
    proxy_list = prox.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    proxy_file = open('proxies.txt', 'w')
    proxy_file.write(proxy_list)
    proxy_file.close()


style.theme_use("cool")
style.configure('body.TFrame', background='#1C2833')
rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    rows += 1

pro_file = open('proxies.txt', 'r')
data = pro_file.read()

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=49, sticky='NESW')

page1 = ttk.Frame(nb, style='body.TFrame')
nb.add(page1, text='Create Tasks')

a = Label(page1, text="Site", bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
a.place(x=8, y=25)
site = Entry(page1, width=20, bg='#212F3D', fg='#FDFEFE')
site.insert(0, 'YeezySupply/Adidas')
site.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click)
site.place(x=10, y=55)

h = Label(page1, text="Tasks:", bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
h.place(x=8, y=135)
num = Entry(page1, width=5, bg='#212F3D', fg='#FDFEFE')
num.place(x=75, y=140)

yes_no = Label(page1, text="Use Proxys?", bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
yes_no.place(x=8, y=220)
y_n = Entry(page1, width=5, bg='#212F3D', fg='#FDFEFE')
y_n.place(x=10, y=250)

headless = Label(page1, text="Headless Mode?", bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
headless.place(x=8, y=330)
y_nh = Entry(page1, width=5, bg='#212F3D', fg='#FDFEFE')
y_nh.place(x=10, y=360)

save = Button(page1, text="Create tasks", bg='#1B2631', fg='#FDFEFE', command=add_tasks)
save.place(x=10, y=650)

page2 = ttk.Frame(nb, style='body.TFrame')
nb.add(page2, text='Tasks')

tasks_id = Label(page2, text='ID', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
tasks_id.place(x=25, y=5)

tasks_stat = Label(page2, text='Page', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
tasks_stat.place(x=95, y=5)

proxy_t = Label(page2, text='Proxy', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
proxy_t.place(x=225, y=5)

status_t = Label(page2, text='Status', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
status_t.place(x=425, y=5)

browser_open = Label(page2, text='Monitoring Browser', bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE', font=("Helvetica", 14))
browser_open.place(x=655, y=5)

page3 = ttk.Frame(nb, style='body.TFrame')
nb.add(page3, text='Proxys')

prox = Text(page3, width=50, height=40, bg='#1C2833', fg='#FDFEFE')
prox.place(x=15, y=15)
prox.insert(END, data)
save_prox = Button(page3, text="Save Proxy", bg='#1B2631', fg='#FDFEFE', command=saveproxy)
save_prox.place(x=15, y=675)

page4 = ttk.Frame(nb, style='body.TFrame')
nb.add(page4, text='Settings')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant code snippets that you're using to create your browsers, and any other bits that you think might be useful for helping us to fully understand the problem and brainstorm solutions?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy i just edited it, please if you need more info just let me know.